# Can you relate entries from more than 1 section?

Tags: templating

Can you relate an entry to entries in two or more different channel/sections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. When creating an entires field the Sources option is where you select which sections you'd like to be able to select entries from. See [Entries Fields in the docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/entries-fields.html).